How to make scripts, extensions for making changes in the app?
I wanted to know  how people create scripts that can make changes in the app. For example there is an app called CODETANTRA in which we can't navigate and copy and paste, but some people bring some software made of scripts, and through that software they can navigate and copy paste easily. People are making extensions that automatically find the answer to the question and mark it; they keep doing this. How they do it. Can anyone tell me so that I can do the same?
How people create extensions through which they automatically finds answer of the question on platforms like hitbullseye, myperfectice, I want to learn it, where I can learn this.
.
